# Emit every signals for each n element in list of QpushButton object

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I have list of QPushButton.i want to be able to make all button in list to emit signals in much more simpler way.

here's my code:

```
 def btn_click(self):
self.menu_list[0].clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_cart(self.menu_list[0]))
self.menu_list[1].clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_cart(self.menu_list[1]))
self.menu_list[2].clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_cart(self.menu_list[2]))
self.menu_list[3].clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_cart(self.menu_list[3]))
self.menu_list[4].clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_cart(self.menu_list[4]))
self.menu_list[5].clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_cart(self.menu_list[5]))
def add_cart(self):
print(b.text())
```

Comment: This sounds like a task for the `QSignalMapper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in loop:

**main**

```
def btn_click(self):
    for button in menu_list:
        button.clicked.connect(self.add_cart)

def add_cart(self):
    b = self.sender()
    print(b.text())
```

**alternative**

```
def btn_click(self):
    for button in self.menu_list:
        button.clicked.connect(lambda btn=button: self.add_cart(btn))
```

Note that you need btn=button for making closure, otherwise all buttons woud refer to the last one.

ps:For more explanation on main way read @ekhumoro comment below

Comment: The `clicked` signal sends a boolean *checked* parameter which will clobber your `btn` argument. Anyway, in this particular case, I think it's better to connect directly to `add_cart` and then use `b = self.sender()` to get the button that sent the signal.

Comment: Thank you,sir.But still it doesn't works.But you gave me an idea to loop it.

Comment: that's not a problem at all, just add wildcard to args in lambda, like this `lambda _, btn=button:...`

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you sir,just as you said i came an idea that same as yours and it works ^_^